# How to find who approved a revision from revisions activity?

Tags: support, review, revisions-list

How can I see who approved the revisions from the revisions history. All I can see is the post was revised.

Comment: If it was a suggested edit, there should be a "suggested" link in the revision history next to the editor's name.

Comment: @Bart It is not a suggested edit but already approved edit.

Comment: "If it **was** a suggested edit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [the revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/195383/revisions) at the right side it is stated whether it is edited or suggested. If it is a suggested edit, it is linked to the review history.

> [image]

And clicking on the suggested link will redirect you to the [review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17491) where you can see who approved/rejected the suggested edit.

> [image]